# HDFS Path for Spark Submit and Flink on YARN

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, apache-flink

i work with cloudera live vm, there i have a hadoop and spral standalone cluster.
now i want submit my jobs with spark submit and flink run scripts. this works, too. but my apps can find the path to input and outputs files in the hdfs.
i set the path like: hdfs://127.0.0.1:50010/user/cloudera/outputs
the information from the port i get from this:
[image]

how to set the path for the hdfs in java??

best regards,
paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to set the path to the DataNode host. On the "Overview" page, you'll see the connection information for the NameNode, and that is also where you have to connect to.

Comment: I think it looks good, but it depends on what user you are running with.

Comment: on cloudera with all permissions, on cloudera live vm i have only the cloudera login.